# Website Not loading on some computers but loads on a single computer on the same LAN

Tags: networking, dns, apache-http-server, webserver, timeout

Like the title says I have a website which loads fine on single computer but won't load on other computers on the same network. The address is [www.360ground.com](http://www.360ground.com)

I have tried pinging it. I get a timeout.

I used the IP address to load the website but still the same result (I guess this rules out any DNS problems).

traceroute output

```
traceroute to 360ground.com (162.144.248.211), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1)  1.500 ms  0.875 ms  3.800 ms
 2  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  3.031 ms  1.977 ms  1.959 ms
 3  10.130.48.1 (10.130.48.1)  23.143 ms  23.084 ms  23.050 ms
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  *
```

I am going crazy over this.

Comment: What does a traceroute tell you?

Comment: it does not finish. I just keeps going displaying asterisks.

Comment: What is the difference between running tracert on the machine that does work and the one that doesn't?

Comment: both have the same result. But still it loads the website.

Comment: Looks like your private networks there don't allow tracing out of the network, so your issue is either within your local networks, or possibly upstream. Speak to your network admin to find out why you cannot traceroute to that destination.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.360ground.com/ looks just fine to me.

I saved it and tried to browse the saved copy and it works reasonably well but with a few issues, eg background is white and the Camera Lens Graphic has vanished!

The Slider and the Graphic Changer still work fine.

A word of warning about your 'Career' Tab which goes to a page headed 'Carrier'

Your issue is plainly a bug in your local Network.

Good Luck with that.

Comment: It is not just on my local network. It doesn't work for few people on other network too.

Answer (score 0):

Going by [this online traceroute](http://network-tools.com/default.asp?prog=trace&host=162.144.248.211) there *might* be an issue with level3.net, as that's where it timed out/finally worked when I ran a trace.